# Selenium script read js file embedded in html

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We are planning to automate with selenium the process to get all js from html page and to find whether a method is called inside the js script, can anyone suggest the approach to do so

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [WebDriver.getPageSource](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) and parse the code according to your needs, e.g. by using a regular expression.

Comment: I have got the js links from the html page with selenium. The js links count 33 and i have to check whether a method is present in the js on all the 33 js links